# how to format datetime for Python Line Graph Bokeh / matplotlib datetime and graph troubles

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, bokeh

I am having some major issues building my first ever line graph and currently I have been working and researching my errors for a long time exhausting all efforts.

I have the following date time example data with sales in the following format. The data is being imported from my MySQL database

```
2015-12-30 01:58:00 10
2015-12-30 01:59:00 16
2015-12-30 02:00:00 21
2015-12-30 02:01:00 5
2015-12-30 02:02:00 2
2015-12-30 02:03:00 4
2015-12-30 02:04:00 11
2015-12-30 02:06:00 5
2015-12-30 02:07:00 10
```

I am working hard on line graphs and would like to complete a line graph in both bokeh and matplotlib. My first choice is the bokeh line graph example [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/plotting.html).

The matplotlib scripts I am using are commented out below.

I have received many, many errors and will list the errors below as I go. The general synopsis of the errors leads me to believe my datetime is not formatted correctly and I do not understand the Auto datetime formatted in matplotlib.
I have also been using regular expressions to sort the date and print the date in the correct format.

```
#row[0] is the date
#row[1] is the sales
2015-12-30 02:09:00 1
2015-12-30 02:10:00 3
2015-12-30 02:12:00 2
2015-12-30 02:13:00 1
2015-12-30 02:14:00 18
2015-12-30 02:15:00 1
2015-12-30 02:16:00 10
2015-12-30 02:17:00 2
```

bokeh example

```
import numpy as np

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import utils
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure

# the import from MYSQL works great and data prints 100% works great
db = MySQLdb.connect("all my database stuff")
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT Statement")
#row[0] is the date in the format above "2015-12-30 02:09:00"
#row[1] is the sales in the format above "1"
try:
    for row in cur.fetchall():
    date = row[0]
    sales = row[1]
    #regex to strip date hypens and colons replace with spaces
    #date_clean = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', date)     
    print date,
    print sales
    #print date_clean prints with no extra characters
except:
    print "error: unable to fetch data"

# prepare some data 
x = 'date'
#x = 'date_clean'
y = 'sales'
# output to static HTML file
output_file("lines.html", title="line plot example")
# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title="example chart", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')
# add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
p.line(x, y, legend="Temp.", line_width=2)
# show the results
show(p)
```

Current errors although I have worked through hundreds of errors. The "lines.html" opens up with a box but no line, dates or sales.

> No handlers could be found for logger
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/validation/check.pyc"
>
> (process:20113): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion
>   'sys_page_size == 0' failed

here is the matplotlib code I am using

```
x = date_clean
y = sales
plt.plot_date(x=date_clean, y=sales)
plt.title("example chart")
plt.ylabel("sales")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
"""
```

Can someone point me in the correct directions. Can anyone help with the correct format for the date time bokeh or matplotlib
requires to execute a correct line graph and can someone explain the current error.

Comment: I don't know `bokeh`, but what is the error you get with `matplotlib`?

Comment: for matplotlib I get the QT output box figure 1. Inside the graph is only a single blue dot in the middle. around the box is empty except for the standard back forward buttons. I get the folioing errors

Comment: when using reg expressions: error  dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum

Comment: When using the date time format above: Error: return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2015-12-30 02:37:00

Comment: return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 2015 12 30 02 37 00

Answer (score 4):

When you provide labels for the `x` and `y`, you should also add a source from which Bokeh can get the actual data, based on those labels. Currently you are telling Bokeh that your `x` and `y` data are strings, which cant be plotted as a line chart.

Different sources are possible, see:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html

So either use:

```
p.line(x, y, source=...)
```

or provide the actual data:

```
p.line(dates, sales)
```

Additionally, when creating the figure, specifying the `x axis` to be a datetime might help, although i dont think thats the main issue here.

```
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", ....
```

Btw, it helps if you create an example that others can run. I don't have your database, so i cant replicate your error, or test my (possible) solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have had/ am having similar issues. I've found a way around this in MPL but not Bokeh.

For Matplotlib:

```
# Format the dates using dates.strftime(format)
# see https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

dates = dates.strftime('%b%d%y') 

# setup figure and axes object
fig = plt.figure(title = 'fig_title_here') #
ax = plt.subplot()

# use regular plot to plot the sales date
ax.plot(range(len(sales)), sales) 
# label x ticks as dates
ax.set_xticklabels([dates])
plt.axis()
```

Hope that helps. 
Also if you find the answer in bokeh, please post it here.